# Header with Subsection title in book class

Tags: sectioning, formatting, header-footer

This is what I have ("Integrales" is just a title, means "Integrals")

[image]

where "Integrals" is a section title and "Analytics Functions Theorems" a subsection title. What I need is the section AND subsection title in the header. That is:

[image]

Please ignore the color of the header, that is not needed. Some of my code is this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}

    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
    

\fancyhead[C]{\ttfamily\nouppercase{\rightmark}}


\begin{document}
     \section{Integrals}
     \subsection{Analytics Functions Theorems}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is quite unclear, because with `book` or `report` the topmost heading level would be `\chapter` not `\section`. And because `oneside` with `book` is also strange, here a suggestion with `report`, `\chapter` and `\section`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
    

\fancyhead[R]{\ttfamily\nouppercase{\leftmark\quad\rightmark}}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Integrals}
\section{Analytics Functions Theorems}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: example with report, chapter, section and fancyhdr]

If you want the page header also on pages with `\chapter` you need to additionally redefine page style `plain` (see section 11 of the `fancyhdr` manual). However, this would not give you the section title on the chapter page, because the second element of `\markboth{#1}{#1}` would be preferred over `\markright`.

With [`scrlayer-scrpage`](https://www.ctan.prg/pkg/scrlayer-scrpage) instead if `fancyhdr` you could use:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
%\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}% also possible

\usepackage[autooneside=false,markcase=used,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ihead[]{}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\ttfamily}
\ohead*{\rightmark: \leftbotmark}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markleft{#1}}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Integrals}
\section{Analytics Functions Theorems}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: result with report, chapter, section and scrlayer-scrpage]

However, this could result in wrong headings, if chapter page does not have a section. But such an issue could be fixed using an explicit `\markleft{}` after the `\chapter{…}` command.

You can do similar with `article` instead of `report` (or `book`) and using `\section` or `\subsection`. Here you don't need to redefine the plain page style:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[autooneside=false,markcase=used,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ihead[]{}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\ttfamily}
\ohead{\rightmark: \leftbotmark}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markleft{#1}}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\section{Integrals}
\subsection{Analytics Functions Theorems}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: result with article, section, subsection and scrlayer-scrpage]

And surely you could do this also using `book`, but IMHO it wouldn't make much sense, and you would have to decide, what to do with chapter pages:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[autooneside=false,markcase=used]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark{section}
\ihead[]{}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\ttfamily}
\ohead{\rightmark: \leftbotmark}% \ohead*{…} instead of \ohead{…} for page header on the chapter pages

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markleft{#1}}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\chapter{What to do with this page?}
\section{Integrals}
\subsection{Analytics Functions Theorems}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: result with book, section, subsection and scrlayer-scrpage]

Note: If you would like to have a line below the page header, `scrlayer-scrpage` provides options `headsepline` and `plainheadsepline`. And if you want to move the page number from the bottom also to the head, you have to use, e.g.,

```
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead*{\rightmark: \leftbotmark\quad\pagemark}
```

See [chapter 5 of the KOMA-Script manual (either in English or German)](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) for more information.

I'm almost sure, similar could be done using `fancyhdr`, but I'm always using `scrlayer-scrpage`, so I know it better.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you! (and sorry for being unclear, i'm still learning how to ask)